# Laravel 4 Email Error

Tags: php, email, laravel

I have been trying to send Email from Laravel and I am getting this error:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException syntax error, unexpected '$message' (T_VARIABLE)

Here is my code:

```
class SubmitBooking extends \BaseController {

public function submit() {

        $data = array('name' => 'test', 'message' => 'test message');
        Mail::pretend('emails.booking', $data, function($message) 
        { 
            $message->to("me@gmail.com", "Name Name")->subject('Welcome to My Laravel app!');         
            $message->from("from@maldivehosting.net", "Name Name");
        });

     }
}
```

I am using PHP latest version, I have tested this on local and and site5 hosting too.
Somebody please help me!

Answer (score 0):

[Per the Laravel documention](http://laravel.com/docs/mail#basic-usage), you cannot use `$message` when creating an email. Try `$msg` instead

```
$data = array('name' => 'test', 'msg' => 'test message');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using Mail::pretend to send your e-mail, it must be a typo. The correct syntax should be:

```
Mail::send('emails.booking', $data, function($msg) 
{ 
    $msg->to("me@gmail.com", "Name Name")->subject('Welcome to My Laravel app!');         
    $msg->from("from@maldivehosting.net", "Name Name");
});
```